# kube-proxy CrashLoopBackOff after kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using `kubeadm` to create a kubernetes v1.9.3 cluster on CentOS 7.4 / Docker 1.12.6. 
I'm following the instructions from [Using kubeadm to Create a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

- after a successful completion of `kubeadm init` I get `kube-proxy` with status `CrashLoopBackOff`

  ```
  # kubectl -n kube-system get pods
  NAME                                  READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
  etcd-ksa-m1.blue                      1/1       Running            0          1m
  kube-apiserver-ksa-m1.blue            1/1       Running            0          1m
  kube-controller-manager-ksa-m1.blue   1/1       Running            0          1m
  kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-24hcr              0/3       Pending            0          2m
  kube-proxy-n5lxp                      0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m
  kube-scheduler-ksa-m1.blue            1/1       Running            0          1m
  ```
- there's an error in `kube-proxy` logs:

  ```
  # kubectl -n kube-system logs kube-proxy-n5lxp
  I0312 16:39:01.667127       1 feature_gate.go:190] feature gates: map[]
  error: unable to read certificate-authority /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt for default due to open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt: no such file or directory
  ```

---

I've found a similar issue reported in kubernetes github: [kubernetes/issues/59461](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59461) but it's open without a solution for quite a while.

- I've also added more details about my environment there: [kubernetes/issues/59461#issuecomment-372385993](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59461#issuecomment-372385993)

Answer (score 0):

I've just found it's related to the docker systemd configuration. I got some docker configs written by puppet.

- the `docker-mountflags.conf` seems to be causing the problem
- I had this config:

  ```
  # cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-mountflags.conf
  [Service]
  MountFlags=private
  ```
- I was able to fix the `kube-proxy` problem by changing this to the default value:

  ```
  # cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-mountflags.conf
  [Service]
  MountFlags=slave
  ```
- after this change I have `kube-proxy` with status `Running`

  ```
  # kubectl -n kube-system get pods
  NAME                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  etcd-ksa-m1.blue                      1/1       Running   0          18m
  kube-apiserver-ksa-m1.blue            1/1       Running   0          18m
  kube-controller-manager-ksa-m1.blue   1/1       Running   0          18m
  kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-lsclt              0/3       Pending   0          19m
  kube-proxy-g29bt                      1/1       Running   0          19m
  kube-scheduler-ksa-m1.blue            1/1       Running   0          18m
  ```